# CMake Link Library Fails in the Docker image

Tags: c++, sqlite, docker, cmake, c++14

When building the docker image of a c++ project I'm facing issues when compiling the project inside the docker image because of a library linking issue

Docker file which is in the https://github.com/chinthakarukshan/jasminegraph/tree/master/docker location builds a docker image on top of ubuntu base image installing the necessary libraries required by the project. When compiling the project I'm getting a library linking issue and fails building the project with below error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [JasmineGraph] Error 1
```

sqlite3 library is already installed in the Dockerfile. But it fails when linking the library.

Below is the cmake code which links the sqlite3 library with the project.

```
target_link_libraries(JasmineGraph sqlite3)
```

Below is the link to the corresponding CMakeList file.

https://github.com/chinthakarukshan/jasminegraph/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Please don’t use link to the files.

Comment: Observed.. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

You need to install dev version:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev
```